# Left join on index failing as per explain plan

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to run the below query and i am joining the tables on the index field ( hdr.M_KEYID)
still i see  TABLE ACCESS FULL in explain plan .
Can you please let me know where did i go wrong and how than this be changed to make it faster

Below are the indexes on each table

Indexes on MY_H2S

```
M_KEY0
M_KEY1
```

Indexes of MY_HBS

```
M_DATE
M_KEYID
M_DATE
```

Query:

```
select 
bdy.M_DATE as M_DATE,
M_KEY0 as M_KEY0,
M_KEY1 as M_KEY1 ,
(M_B_F+M_A_F)/2  as M_PRICE,
bdy.M_DATE as M_DATE
from 
MY_H2S hdr left join MY_HBS bdy on hdr.M_KEYID = bdy.M_KEYID
```

Explain Plan :

```
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Id  | Operation          | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |             |   182K|    12M|   458   (1)| 00:00:06 |
 |*  1 |  HASH JOIN OUTER   |             |   182K|    12M|   458   (1)| 00:00:06 |
 |   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| MY_H2S      |   124 |  3968 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
 |   3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| MY_HBS      |   182K|  7288K|   455   (1)| 00:00:06 |
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can you please let mw know where did i go wrong and how than this be chnaged to make it faster

Comment: Can you add indexes of your tables?

Comment: no , icant add new indexes

Comment: Why are you so sure an index lookup for every row won't make it slower? You could try hinting it and check the I/O and timings. By the way, the join isn't failing, it's just picking a different execution plan to the one you expected.

Comment: the main rule for the CBO in using index or not using is the retreiving number of the rows. in that example that is ~182K what is really huge for using index, full table scan is cheaper. Keep that mind: full table scan is not a monster

Comment: Does this mean query cant be optimized further, any advice?

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

Personally, I would expect Oracle to use the `MY_HBS(M_KEYID)` for the `JOIN`.  However, there are mitigating circumstances:

- The table is small, fitting (presumably) on one page.
- The index does not cover the query (you are selecting other columns).

The optimizer is balancing multiple considerations.  Linearly scanning a list of 124 records is not necessarily worse than loading an index, traversing the index, and then loading the (single) database.